# Unable to install PSQL

Tags: linux, psql, rhel, dnf

What is the meaning of this error?

I added the PSQL for the [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 8 repository and am struggling to install the PSQL server because of an unknown error (as root):

```
cd ~
dnf install postgresql15-server
```

Output:

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.

This system is registered with an entitlement server, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.

Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:52 ago on Sun 18 Jun 2023 08:17:28 AM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: package postgresql15-server-15.3-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 requires postgresql15(x86-64) = 15.3-2PGDG.rhel8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides lz4 needed by postgresql15-15.3-2PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Comment: How is this on-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the license for your RHEL operating system is not correctly registered. Assuming you have a valid license, you can use `subscription-manager` to activate RHEL with your license, and after that `dnf` command should work as expected.

Comment: Everything works well after registering my vm and attaching it to my Red Hat Developer Subscription on my Subscription Manager. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, please consider upvoting to help others with the same problem.